# Creating a script for modifying several users crontabs

Tags: scripts, cron, rtorrent, rutorrent

I run a seed-box like local machine with Ubuntu 14.04LTS setup with multi-user rtorrent/rutorrent.

I installed that through a script that also installed crontab entries for each user so rtorrent & irrsi would start automatically at boot.

Load is too high (especially on the network) if all users rtorrent/irrsi are running at the same time.
So I have started to

```
su - user
password
crontab -e
```

& then comment these rtorrent/irrsi lines out for users A-D
& uncomment them for users E-H.

Later at night, when I return from work, I do the same but uncomment these lines for users A-D & comment these lines out for users E-H.

All this editing has made me starting to wonder if there wouldn't be an easier way to accomplish this...
Would there be a way of creating a script that adds a # in front of all the lines in the crontab of all the users I specify.
And then maybe a second script to remove that # (if present).

EDIT: each users' crontab contains only these 2 lines.

```
@reboot sleep 10; /usr/local/bin/rtcheck irssi rtorrent
*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/rtcheck irssi rtorrent
```

When I don't want them to be run at reboot or later, when cron finds them not running, I just comment out these lines so they look like this:

```
#@reboot sleep 10; /usr/local/bin/rtcheck irssi rtorrent
#*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/rtcheck irssi rtorrent
```

making it effectively neither irssi nor rtorrent start a boot nor get started later when cron finds them not running.

Comment: Welcome to AU ! Can you show us a couple of those `crontab` entries ? (Please add them a the end of yr original post.)

Comment: Should we assume this is a regular user's `crontab` and not root's ?

Comment: dont! use `/etc/crontab` No need to mess with every users crontab when you can use that one and include a username. 1 place to store them. 1 place to edit them. And you reaaaaaaaaally should check the user name in a script and not edit crontabs.

Comment: No, I don't want to do this for the root crontab, only for all other users related to rtorrent.
I just added the entries that are in each users crontab (except root).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way of doing this with `cron` is to:

- start the torrent service at time T1 for each user in user group A
- stop the torrent service at time T2>T1 for users in group A
- start the torrent service at time T2>T1 for users in group B
- stop the torrent service at time T3>T2 for users in group B

Choose times, e.g.

- T1 is anywhere between 0:01 am and 1:59 pm on D-day
- T2 is 2:00 pm on D-day
- T3 is 11:59 pm on D-day

You can change that anyway you like to make time sharing equitable for all group A and B users.

For user "username" in group A:
1) Edit existing `crontab` entries by commenting them out. Don't erase them just comment them out so they do not fire.
2) Add new `crontab` entries:

```
# => either start daemon, while checking that (i) startup takes place between 0:01 am
#+ and 2:00pm and (i) no 'rtorrent' process owned by "username" already runs. 
*/10 0-14 * * * [ -z $(/bin/ps -eF | /usr/bin/awk '/rtorrent/ && /username/') ] && /sbin/start-stop-daemon -S /usr/local/bin/rtorrent  
# => or start client-app based on similar conditions
*/10 0-14 * * * [ -z $(/bin/ps -eF | /usr/bin/awk '/rtorrent/ && /username/') ] && /usr/bin/env DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/local/bin/rtorrent  

# stop 'rtorrent' process if it exists and is owned by "username"
#+ Check every 5 minutes between 2pm and midnight
*/5 14-24 * * * /usr/bin/kill "$(/bin/ps -eF | /usr/bin/awk '/rtorrent/ && /username/ printf "%s",$2')"  > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Details of the command starting yr daemon will depend on a number of factors, e.g. whether the client starting `rtorrent` is a single user machine or whether several user can simultaneously run their own instance of `rtorrent`. In this case you may want to save the process pid in a run-file for each user so you can manage those processes as a unction of traffic load. Look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797373/rtorrent-init-script-not-working) to actually start the `rtorrent` process identifying user, socket and pid.

*I could **not** tried this solution, so it is a bit of a foray in the dark as far as the correct start procedure is concerned. In particular I assume that yr `/home/username/.rtorrent.rc` is adequately configured, and that `irssi` gives you no trouble as detailed [elsewhere](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563659/how-can-i-run-a-command-at-start-up-on-ubuntu-server-not-as-root).*

HTH. Please report.

Comment: I wasn't really looking to schedule it at fixed times. I'd rather run a command at a moment of my convenience that'll kill the running instances I don't want to be running & fires up the instances I do want.
However, since seeing your solution, I have started to like the idea more & more. I will give it a try.

Comment: If you mention the `cron` flag and you show a crontab entry in PO, then it's logical to surmise that you want to run the jobs automatically and not manually. Note that the crontab enty I included are solutions that fire up the service _at any time_ between midnight and 2pm  after boot for group A users, and to shut down the _same_ `rtorrent` client  any time between  2pm and midnight. I propose that, so that any group A user that fires up his/her torrent`client after 2pm will see it being automatically closed after 5 minutes tops. Doing so you actually regulate `rtorrent` usage by group.  HTH

Comment: You can do the same for group B users and their `rtorrent`sessions. You can actually partition yr 24 hrs in any number of times windows to accommodate any number of user groups, so that you concede to them the possibility to run `rtorrent` during a time period you specify in advance.

Comment: OK, I admit my way of putting the question was a bit misleading. I already told I gonna try your solution. I have not yet been able to implement it though. I plan on doing 3 groups which each get 8 hours of the day.